# Organising fragments Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Hi I have my application showing google maps. I basically want to move the fragment it is in til the top right hand side of the screen so that I can add other things. Can anyone advise me where to start please? My layout is below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >     
<fragment        
    android:id="@+id/map"        
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add the other views first then relative to the views oraganize fragment in the place you want. or put tfragment where you want and organize views relative to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the other views to your layout. You can place the fragment relative to other views.

You can adjust the height and width of the fragment to suit your needs

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Or

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```